# use vba to close a file whose name is specified in a workbook cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am using VBA to iterate through rows in a table.
For each row the code (where I refer to the rows as "scenario")
opens a file path specified in column 6,
does something, and
closes the file path specified in column 6

I am trying to execute the code below; however, it is failing because the file name must be specified as a string. I cannot do this because the file name will be different for each row in my table

`Workbooks("scenario.Columns(6)", False).Close`

What is the proper syntax to close a file using a cell reference for the name of the file?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**1.** If `scenario` range contains *one* row, to get the value in sixth column you need to use:

```
Workbooks(scenario.Cells(,6)).Close False
```

**2.** If `scenario` range contains *few* rows,  to get the value in sixth column you need to specify row number as well (i.e. second):

```
Workbooks(scenario.Cells(2,6)).Close False
```

**UPD:**

Try this one (following from comments):

```
Dim Scenario As Range
Dim input_table As Range

'Identifying input table
Set input_table = Sheets("Input").[Scenario_input]

'iterate through rows in table
For Each Scenario In input_table.Rows
    If Scenario.Columns(5).Value = "Yes" Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Scenario.Columns(6).Value
        'do something
        '
        'Close the scenario workbook
        Workbooks(Scenario.Columns(6).Value).Close False
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Try now. I've updated unswer. Btw, `scenario` it's the range object? and you need to get sixth column of it?

Comment: 'scenario' is my row number (in a sense)

Comment: Im using a for loop to iterate through my table: For scenario in table

Comment: I dont want the row number to be hard coded because for each "scenario" that you go through, you want to close the file in column 6 of that scenario (row)

Comment: See my updated answer with `For each` loop. I don't understand what you store in `scenario` - row number or row? If row, then `Workbooks(scenario.Cells(,6)).Close False` should work. If row number, try something like this: `Workbooks(Cells(scenario,6)).Close False`. It would be great if you update your Q with more code (where you define `scenario`)

Comment: 'Identifying input table                                          Set input_table = Sheets("Input").[Scenario_input]                                                    'iterate through rows in table For Each Scenario In input_table                                                       If Scenario.Columns(5).Value = "Yes" Then Workbooks.Open Filename:=Scenario.Columns(6)                                        'Close the scenario workbook Workbooks(Scenario.Column(6).Value).Close False

Comment: Your code doesn't iterates through rows, it's iterates through cells of `Scenario_input` table. To iterate through rows you need to use `For Each Scenario In input_table.Rows` instead `For Each Scenario In input_table`. See my updated answer